# Space around mid-arrow xymatrix labels

Tags: spacing, labels, xymatrix

I'd like the top figure here (the one in the MWE) to look like the bottom figure (which was made by changing the labels into targets etc., but I have a lot of these diagrams to change and would rather a simpler fix), ie. with legibly spaced labels. I feel as though there should be some label equivalent along the lines of the @R=5pt etc. options to adjust spacing throughout the diagram, but it is eluding me. I guess @L is close, but doesn't seem to work for mid-arrow labels. Suggestions much appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    \xymatrix{
      \bullet \ar@{-}[d]|1\ar@{-}[dr]|2\ar@{-}[drr]|3 & \bullet & \bullet\ar@{=}[d]|{45}\\
      \bullet & \bullet & \bullet
    }
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

I guess I could contrive a regex to add, say, *+<5pt> for every label, but I feel there must be some nicer trick, especially given how borderline illegible the default seems to be.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This adds to *every* label some space around it.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\makeatletter
\def\labelbox#1{%
  \hbox{%
    \setbox\z@=\hbox{$\m@th\labelstyle{\,#1\,}$}%
    \setbox\tw@=\hbox{$\m@th\labelstyle\,$}%
    \dimen@=\ht\z@ \advance\dimen@ by \wd\tw@ \ht\z@=\dimen@
    \dimen@=\dp\z@ \advance\dimen@ by \wd\tw@ \dp\z@=\dimen@
    \box\z@
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    \xymatrix{
      \bullet \ar@{-}[d]|1\ar@{-}[dr]|2\ar@{-}[drr]|3 & \bullet & \bullet\ar@{=}[d]|{45}\\
      \bullet & \bullet & \bullet
    }
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `tikz-cd`

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzcd}[arrows=no head,row sep=large]
  \bullet \arrow[d,"1" description] \arrow[dr,"2" description]
          \arrow[drr,"3" description] &
  \bullet &
  \bullet\arrow[d,equal,"45" description]\\
  \bullet & \bullet & \bullet
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @egreg. This first solution works for me, though as you point out, other diagrams' labels may need tweaking. I've upvoted, but won't mark as accepted yet, in case there is a solution more "inbuilt" into xymatrix.